# Regular Expression to eliminate repeated patterns

Tags: python, text, replace

I want to eliminate certain tags and their value from texts.

For example, I have text like

{A}a-value-1;{B}b-value-1;{C}c-value-1;{A}a-value-2;{B}b-value-2;{C}c-value-2

Expected value if lets say tag B need to be removed.
{A}a-value-1;{C}c-value-1;{A}a-value-2;{C}c-value-2

Another expected value if lets say tag A need to be removed.
{B}b-value-1;{C}c-value-1;{B}b-value-2;{C}c-value-2

Language I am using is Python on Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.sub` as follows:

```py
inp = "{A}a-value-1;{B}b-value-1;{C}c-value-1;{A}a-value-2;{B}b-value-2;{C}c-value-2"
output = re.sub(r'\{B\}[^;]+;?', '', inp)
print(output)  # {A}a-value-1;{C}c-value-1;{A}a-value-2;{C}c-value-2
```

The regex pattern used above says to match:

- `\{B\}` literal `{B}`
- `[^;]+` followed by one or more characters other than semicolon
- `;?` optional semicolon ending